# Working with tabs in MvvmCross

Tags: android, ios, mvvmcross

I'm trying to make a tabbed app using MvvmCross but can't seem to find a working sample showing how it would be done. All of the samples I've seen are for a previous version, which haven't been updated and seem to be missing some of the necessary changes for the update to latest.

Considering this example:
https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Tutorials/blob/master/Sample%20-%20CirriousConference/Cirrious.Conference.UI.Touch/Views/TabBarController.cs

What changes would I need to make to that class to get it working with the latest version of MvvmCross?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how I use tabs on my apps. I'm using MvvmCross 4.4.0.

AppDelegate.cs:

```
[Register("AppDelegate")]
public partial class AppDelegate : MvxApplicationDelegate
{
    private UIWindow window;

    public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
    {
        this.window = new UIWindow(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);

        Setup setup = new Setup(this, this.window);
        setup.Initialize();

        IMvxAppStart startup = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxAppStart>();
        startup.Start();

        this.window.MakeKeyAndVisible();

        return true;
    }
}
```

Setup.cs:

```
public class Setup : MvxIosSetup
{
    public Setup(MvxApplicationDelegate applicationDelegate, UIWindow window) : base(applicationDelegate, window)
    {
    }

    protected override IMvxApplication CreateApp()
    {
        return new Core.App();
    }
}
```

HomeView.cs:

```
public class HomeView : MvxTabBarViewController<HomeViewModel>
{
    private bool _constructed;

    public HomeView()
    {
        _constructed = true;

        // need this additional call to ViewDidLoad because UIkit creates the view before the C# hierarchy has been constructed
        ViewDidLoad();
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        if (!_constructed)
            return;

        base.ViewDidLoad();

        var viewControllers = new UIViewController[]
        {
            CreateTabFor(0, "First", "FirstImage", typeof(FirstViewModel)),
            CreateTabFor(1, "Second", "SecondImage", typeof(SecondViewModel)),
            CreateTabFor(2, "Third", "ThirdImage", typeof(ThirdViewModel))
        };

        ViewControllers = viewControllers;
        CustomizableViewControllers = new UIViewController[] { };

        //Sometimes I need to start with a specific tab selected
        SelectedViewController = ViewControllers[ViewModel.CurrentPage];
    }

    private UIViewController CreateTabFor(int index, string title, string imageName, Type viewModelType)
    {
        var controller = new UINavigationController();
        var request = new MvxViewModelRequest(viewModelType, null, null, null);
        var viewModel = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxViewModelLoader>().LoadViewModel(request, null);
        var screen = this.CreateViewControllerFor(viewModel) as UIViewController;
        screen.Title = title;
        screen.TabBarItem = new UITabBarItem(title, UIImage.FromBundle(imageName), index);
        controller.PushViewController(screen, true);
        return controller;
    }
}
```

FirstView.cs, SecondView.cs, ThirdView.cs and all others tabbed views:

```
public class FirstView : MvxViewController<FirstViewModel>
{
    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();

        //Your view content...
    }
}
```

Github repository with Android and iOS sample: https://github.com/rrispoli/SampleTabs

Comment: Rafael - this is super helpful.  Any chance you could post a link to an example in GitHub that just shows tab menus working in ios and android using this approach?  I'd happily donate to your favorite charity ! :)

Comment: Yes, I will create a sample project in the next days and I leave here the GitHub link. :)

Comment: Hi Rafael, if you get a chance to post that sample project, it would be appreciated :)